# Angular, dynamic styles between style tags

Tags: angular

Looking to update values between style tags depending on input given by user, can't use class binding in this case.
I can make inline styles work, the only issue is hover styles and media queries, so this isn't a solution either.
Is there any way so that this variable can be applied for a css value between style tags?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teststyle',
  template: `
    <h1>Text ({{color}})</h1>
    <style>h1 {color:{{color}}}h1:hover{color:{{colorHover}}}</style>
  `,
  styles: [
    `  
      h1 {color: $color}
      h1:hover {color:blue}
    `
  ]
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  color: string = "red";
  colorHover: string = "blue"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check **NgStyle** https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

To implement the hover you should use `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to manipulate the color

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teststyle',
  template: `
    <h1 [ngStyle]="style" (mouseover)="onMouseOver()" (mouseout)="onMouseOut()">Text ({{color}})</h1>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  color: string = "red";
  colorHover: string = "blue"

  style: any = { 'color': ''}

  constructor() {
    this.style = { 'color': this.color};
  }

  onMouseOver() {
    this.style.color = this.colorHover
  }

  onMouseOut(){
    this.style.color = this.color;
  }

}
```